# Pushing over a block

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Consider a rectangular block of mass $m$ and uniform density resting on a frictionless surface. The height is $h$, the width $w$, the length $l$. Consider one of the faces with dimmensions $l$ by $h$. Locate the point along the line passing through the center of this face and perpendicular to the frictionless surface, at a height $x$ above the surface. You apply a force $F$ on this point. What is the minimum value of $F$ required to make the block fall over? Does it matter how long you apply the force $F$?

There is the related and more general question: if you push an object on a frictionless surface, will it topple over, and under what cases on a friction surface will it topple over?

Comment: Think about what type of force (acting on the bottom of the block) would normally cause it to tip and fall over, and whether or not this would exist in your scenario.

Comment: I guess you are hinting at the related question: can the block fall over if there is no friction?

Comment: Ive made several attempts to understand the problem and I've generalized with OP. I feel understanding this physics concept can be useful to the broader community, so please unlock.

Answer (score 2):

If the block is resting on a frictionless surface, it won't fall over. It'll set in horizontal motion even with little force.

To create torque, one edge of the bottom surface of the block needs to be fixed with high static friction and there must be a non-zero angle between the force and the line connecting force application point and fixed point (you can achieve this by applying inclined force having a vertical component or by applying horizontal force above the level of fixed point).

Comment: Imagine standing on a train, and the train accelerates. The friction on your feet pulls your feet with the train, but the only force pulling your head forward is internal to your body, and I this internal force can be less than the friction force, I believe. Thus your head does not accelerate with your feet, and you topple over. Considering my OP, if you apply a force on the person's feet, even if the ground is frictionless, you can simulate the friction force from the train situtation, so the guy should topple over, right?

Comment: @Joshua No way. If ground is frictionless, an accelerated frame can't create torque. Note: With accelerated frame, you can simulate gravity, not friction.

Comment: Ok, it's not that intuitive, but I understand why no torque is created. But if we have a surface with friction, a force parallel to the surface should produce torque, at least if the force is applied above the center of gravity, no?

Comment: But intuitively it seems this should be the case. Imagine a rectangular block with a thin base resting on a table with friction. If you apply a force parallel to the ground at the topmost point, the block falls over.

Comment: @Joshua Updated the question to support horizontal force applied above the level of fixed point.